# Function output contradicts function constraints

Tags: matlab

I wrote a function that takes as an imput a natural number 'n', and outputs a random walk, starting at 0, where each subsequent entry in the vector is obtained by adding or subtracting 1 to the previous entry. The random walk has to stop whenever it reaches n or -n.

The code is the following

```
function [N] = rand_walk2(n)
j=0; %J will be the outpur of the function
v=0; %Defines variable v.
i=2; %The following 'while' loop will start from the second entry of the vector.
while abs(j(i-1)) < n %This 'while' loop will continue running only if the previous entry is strictly between -n and n.
if rand >= 0.5 %This 'if' statement returns 1 or -1 with equal probability (it uses the uniform distribution with parameters [0,1]).
    v = 1;
else v = -1;
end
    j(i)=j(i-1)+v;
    j = [j,j(i)];
    i=i+1;    
end
N = j;
end
```

The problem is that the output returns n or -n twice instead of only once, for example, if I evaluate `rand_walk2(3)` I get `0 -1 -2 -3 -3` instead of just `o -1 -2 -3`. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I can change to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Line 10 pushes the current position into vector `j`

```
j(i)=j(i-1)+v;
```

and then line 11 concatenates that same value on to the end of the array

```
j = [j,j(i)];
```

Simply remove line 11.

---

As a usual side note, the symbols `i` and `j` are often used to produce imaginary numbers and often mistakenly as indexing variables.  It is [recommended by Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/i.html#moreabout):

> Since `i` is a function, it can be overridden and used as a variable. However, it is best to avoid using `i` and `j` for variable names if you intend to use them in complex arithmetic.

In this case, it is not necessary, but I like to promote good programming practices when I can (also, I needed to force my brain to think through your code because of this practice).